# HTML - Img alt attribute hides image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

I'm grabbing favicon's from sites programmatically by generically making a request for the icon to "example.com/favicon.ico".

If the site doesn't have a favicon, I want to use the "alt" attribute of the image to hide the image so that it doesn't appear and doesn't have a "missing image" icon.

For example

```
<img src="https://www.businessinsider.com/favicon.ico" alt="$(this).hide();" height="16" width="16">
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes the source fills, but then the file isnt found. In my implementation there's no way to check beforehand

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `error()` method. Hide your image based upon that.

```js
$("img").on("error", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.businessinsider.com/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16">
```

If you want an alternative image when the image is not available, give the new image source.

```js
$("img").on("error", function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/mountain.png");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.businessinsider.com/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16">
```

Comment: What about using a function in the onerror tag within the image?

Comment: @SteveAlereza See the example here: [element.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#element.onerror)

Answer (score 1):

You can put your placeholder immediately and check if the image loads on script. If it loads, replace the `img src`

```js
var thisImage = new Image();
thisImage.src = 'https://www.businessinsider.com/favicon.ico';
thisImage.onload = function() {
  console.log("Image 1 ready to append");
  document.querySelector('.bg-image').src = thisImage.src;
};
```

```html
<!--The source here is your placeholder-->
<img class="bg-image" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" height="50" width="50" />
```